# Unable to save the product stock status as "Out of stock" in magento 2

Tags: backend, magento2.2.4, save, stock-status

I have imported a single product via backend.

The product stock status is mentioned as 0 ("is_in_stock => 0") in csv sheet which i imported.

The product successfully saved. But while opening the product in backend the stock status saved as "In stock".

Then I have manually tried to change the stock status as "Out of stock" and saved the product. But the stock status is not updated.

Still shows as "In Stock".Please provide me a solution.

> Note: But I can change the stock status of some of the
>    products

My question is why Magento not automatically change the stock status as "out of stock" if the quantity is 0?

I have tried to change the the status by using Advance Inventory option, but no luck

[image]

Comment: Please do reindexing and then save it again

Comment: Have you check the inventory

Comment: Reindexed no use. But if the quantity is 0, then why  the stock status is not automatically changed ?

Answer (score 0):

*In that case, you have to mark them to manage stock = Yes and set it as out of stock.*

*on product edit page in backend when you click on Advanced Inventory, you will see that page*

*What you have to do is set specific product to
Manage Stock = Yes and
Stock Status = Out of Stock*

*see Attched screenshot*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi , I have tried Waht you have said above,but no luck

Comment: @jaisa did you check in All Store View ? 
And Please do reindexing

Comment: I have only one default store view